# Could not Connect different host to retrieve value

Tags: python, mysql

```
def main():
global L1Aresult
global L5Aresult
global total
global limit
global trigger
global check
x=0
while True:
    try:
        L1A = pymysql.connect(host="10.8.22.59",port = 3306,user = "root",passwd="root",db="halm_tables")
        L5A = pymysql.connect(host="10.8.22.3",port = 3306,user = "root",passwd="root",db="halm_tables") 
        break
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

        continue
    finally:
        pass

sqlstr = """SELECT UniqueID,TestDate,Testtime, EL2FingerDefaultCount FROM halm_tables.halm_results ORDER BY uniqueid Desc limit 1"""
L1Acursor = L1A.cursor()
L1Acursor.execute(sqlstr)

previous=L1Aresult
L1Aresult = L1Acursor.fetchall()
```

**When one of the host connection is closed, the program will not skip that closed connection and continue the execution. What happened to my code??**

Comment: so if L1A is down, do you expect the code to use L5A? I don't see in your code any use of L5A.

Comment: yes i would like L5A to continue the execution. Assuming L5Acursor = 51A.cursor()
L5Acursor.execute(sqlstr), L5Aresult = L5Acursor.fetchall() are all correctly coded. The problem i faced is that the program stopped when L1A disconnected. I want to get it continue running and ignore the disconnected host

Comment: it works now. My bot will send a message to the group if the input reached certain level. However, my bot cannot run for a day. It always stop after 1 to 2 hours due to telegram-bot connection timed out error

Answer (score 0):

This code will loop till it finds a healthy server. Then it would fetch the results and bail out. I kept your global variables, but I think you should create a class like Host which has data members like cursor, result, previous, etc. This would allow refactoring this code and remove some redundancies.

```
sqlstr = """SELECT UniqueID,TestDate,Testtime, EL2FingerDefaultCount FROM halm_tables.halm_results ORDER BY uniqueid Desc limit 1"""

while True:
    try:
        L1A = pymysql.connect(host="10.8.22.59",port = 3306,user = "root",passwd="root",db="halm_tables")
        L1Acursor = L1A.cursor()
        L1Acursor.execute(sqlstr)
        previous = L1Aresult
        L1Aresult = L1Acursor.fetchall()
        break
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    try:
        L5A = pymysql.connect(host="10.8.22.3",port = 3306,user = "root",passwd="root",db="halm_tables") 
        L5Acursor = L5A.cursor()
        L5Acursor.execute(sqlstr)
        previous = L5Aresult
        L5Aresult = L5Acursor.fetchall()
        break
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```